# How do I add an image to the end of a header?

Tags: image, wordpress, widget

I have a wordpress website that I need to add an image to the end of each header. The problem is that these are widgets and all text is replaced by the widget in wordpress. Is there a way I can hard code the image to the end of the header so it won't be erased?

```
<div class="grid_4 widget">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer 1') ) : ?>
<h2 class="beeh2">Widgetized Area 1</h2>
<p>Go to Appearance - Widgets section to overwrite this section. Use any widgets that fits you best. This is called <strong>Bottom Left</strong>.</p>
<?php endif; ?> 
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid_4 widget">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Footer 2') ) : ?>
<h2 class="beeh2">Widgetized Area 2</h2>
<p>Go to Appearance - Widgets section to overwrite this section. Use any widgets that fits you best. This is called <strong>Bottom Middle</strong>.</p>
<?php endif; ?> 
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I've also noticed the h2 class I've created also isn't there when I check the website. That appears to also be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your functions.php (or file included there) you should see "register_sidebar".  Footer 1 and Footer 2 are custom sidebars and are probably overwriting the code you are placing in the widget.  Look for something like the code below.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'Footer 1',
    'id'            => 'footer-1',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '',
    'after_title'   => '',
) );
```

The 'before_title' and 'after_title probably contain your h2.  Using html you can add your image in the 'after_title'.

Hope that helps!